# Erro ao listar dados em AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

Olá!
Estou listando dados e ao mesmo tempo está me apontando erro, porém não sei como corrigir.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados que estão sendo listados vem assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu código

```
<div id="inputGrupo">
    <select class="form-control contaGrupo" name="categoria" id="" ng-model="conta.grupo" required>
        <option value="">Selecione o grupo...</option>
        <option ng-repeat="g in grupos" value="{{ g.idgrupo }}">{{ g.grupo }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Como corrigir esse erro?

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de erro é clara, você tem chaves duplicadas na array, sempre bom definir o `track by` no ng-repeat no exemplo que você colocou seria:

```
<div id="inputGrupo">
   <select class="form-control contaGrupo" name="categoria" id="" ng-model="conta.grupo" required>
      <option value="">Selecione o grupo...</option>
      <option ng-repeat="g in grupos track by g.idcategoria" value="{{ g.idgrupo }}">{{ g.grupo }}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Vou tentar novamente, mas já tentei fazer o que você sugeriu eu não mudou kkkkk

Comment: Em último caso tente definir ng-repeat="(key, g) in grupos track by key"